# Proxmox options for Hard disk and CPU tab

Tags: proxmox

While creating a KVM Virtual Machine in proxmox from the GUI, for the hard disk and CPU tab there are a couple of options that are confusing.

For example, this is the hard disk tab,

[image]

In that tab, what does "No backup", "Discard" and "Iothread" signify?

And similarly, this is the CPU tab,

[image]

In this tab, what does "Sockets", "Cores" and "Enable numa" mean?

I did not have any luck with google and the results that I got were conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

**No backup** instructs proxmox to not perform any backups for that VM.

**Discard** allows the guest to use fstrim or the discard option to free up the unused space from the underlying storage system. This is only usable on a virtio_scsi driver.

**Iothread** sets the AIO mode to threads (instead of native). For more information check [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/pradeepkumarsuvce/qemu-disk-io-which-performs-better-native-or-threads).

**Sockets** is the number of CPUs that the guest will see as installed/available.

**Cores** is the number of cores that the guest will be able to use for each CPU.

If your server has 2 sockets each with a CPU that has 6 cores you could put 2 in the *Sockets* and 6 in the *Cores* fields and the guest will be able to use 100% of both CPU's. You can also put 1 in *Sockets* and 3 in *Cores* fields and the guest will be able to use only 50% from one CPU, so only 25% of the available CPU power on the server.

**Enable Numa** will allow the guest to make use of the [NUMA architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access) (servers with more than 2 sockets) on specific servers. Check www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/20/Best-practices-for-KVM-on-NUMA-servers